# First time ubuntu Intel GMA3150 on NB30 Plus

Tags: 11.10, intel-graphics, ubuntu-netbook, samsung

I have intel atom N450 and intel GMA3150 when looking in system info it says unknown for the GPU and youtube videos above 360p laag very bad compared to windows xp 720p was smooth.

I don't know much about Linux this is like the first step I have taken to try and use Linux rather than Windows. Please can some one help me out and explain what I have to do.

```
~$ lspci -nnk | grep -A2 VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation N10 Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:a011] 
Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device [144d:c073] 
    Kernel driver in use: i915
```

Answer (score 0):

Type

sudo apt-get install mesa-utils

in the terminal and then check system info and youtube (to test 720p) everything will be hunky doory.

If you run glxinfo in terminal you should see you have direct rendering.

Answer (score -1):

Hi and welcome to AskUbuntu!

The System Info shows pretty much anything as unknown, no matter what hardware is used. To verify that your hardware is properly recognized, run the following is terminal (ctrl+alt+t):

```
lspci -nnk | grep -A2 VGA
```

The output should show both the hardware and the driver in use.
For a more user friendly way, install 'Hardinfo' from the repositories.

Both Adobe Flash and Intel's GMA3150 perform very badly on Linux when compared to Windows. There are several alternatives for Adobe Flash, mostly for youtube, not sure they'd suite your needs.

For example, [Minitube](http://flavio.tordini.org/) ..., or whatever it's called now.

Another alternative is a Firefox extension called [FlashVideoReplacer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flashvideoreplacer/).

Comment: Hey this is what it displayed it: 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation N10 Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:a011] Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device [144d:c073] Kernel driver in use: i915

Comment: That shows the hardware is properly recognized, and you are good to go.